# How to make a field indexed in Kibana?

Tags: indexing, visualization, kibana

I have imported json data from Kafka to elasticsearch and I can see them in Kibana > Discover. But, on the left panel, under 'Available Fields', all my fields have a '?' and says 'Not indexed'. Because of this, I am unable to visualize the data. I read somewhere that I would have to change mapping to make the fields indexed. I couldn't see an example anywhere? Any idea on how I can make my data visualize in Kibana? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go on the settings tab and reload the field of the index pattern where you data are.

Answer (score 0):

You need create template for elasticsearch for mapping fields, for example packetbeat template: 
https://github.com/elastic/beats/blob/master/packetbeat/etc/packetbeat.template.json

How to load template:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/packetbeat/current/packetbeat-getting-started.html#packetbeat-template